# How many bandages does a Gnome use up when bleeding?

Tags: gnomoria

My gnomes seem to bleed a lot and use a lot of Bandages. It is not like I don't have an excess amount of cotton, but I can barely keep up with production to satisfy they are need for treating their wounds.

**How many bandages does a Gnome use up when bleeding?**

Does he use 1 Bandage for each wound? Or 1 Bandage each time he is injured?

Answer (score 4):

Wiki post on **[Wounds](http://www.gnomoriawiki.com/wiki/Gnomes#Wounds)**:

*Wounds are applied to individual limbs, and can be viewed in the Gnome's Health tab. **All healable injuries require bandages***.

From how this is phrased, I would guess that bandages are used on a per-injury basis, and since injuries are inflicted on a per-limb basis (as per above), I would assume one bandage per injury/limb is required, and that one bandage will not heal an entire gnome.

Comment: I will try to record it, but I am 99% sure that the gnome will use one bandage for each wound.  ie. Wounds list: Right hand is bleeding, left hand is injured, left eye is injured. -> uses 3 bandages.  (I had a bad fight where 6 gnomes came back with injuries and my stash of 20 bandages disappeared.  Unfortunately, the remaining wounded included my tailor who would not make more bandages until the injury was healed. So I had a character make a bandage, but the tailor had two wounds so, after I forced a second bandage to be made, he made more for everyone else and restocked.)